# isc-dhcp-server not work in openstack's instance but work in vmware

Tags: udp, instance, openstack, dhcp

Through `tcpdump` in `dhcp-server`, it shows the **server** can receive the `DHCPDISCOVER` package and send the `DHCPOFFER` package, but can not receive the `DHCPREQUEST` package from the `dhcp-client`, so the **client** can not get IP address and always in send `DHCPDISCOVER` package.

But the `dhcp-server` which runs in **VMWARE**'s instance can send `DHCPACK` to **client** and the same **client** will get the IP success. The `dhcp-server` using the same configure as in **Openstack**'s instance.

And, if I configure the static IP address in the **client** instance, it will `ping` the `dhcp-server`'s IP successful.

One more thing, the **server** and **client** are in the same `vlan`.

Is there any limit rule in `Openstack`'s instance? How can I resolve this problem, THX.

Answer (score 0):

The essential reason is that the `traffic` of `port` is limited by the `security groups` in `openstack`.

[By default, all security groups contain a series of basic (sanity) and anti-spoofing rules that perform the following actions:](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/networking-guide/intro-os-networking.html)

> Deny egress DHCP and DHCPv6 responses to prevent instances from acting as DHCP(v6) servers.

Resolution:

- **disable** `security groups` (no recommend)
- set `dhcp-relay` to the **dhcp server** in `router` (recommend)
- - `security groups` limited the traffic by hypervisor's `iptables` which will drop the packets which's `src port is 67 and dst port is 68`.
- - `DHCPOFFER` packets will send to `router` by `src and dst port 67`, and [it will works to all vlans](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/routing-policy/topics/concept/dhcp-extended-firewall-filter-overview.html).

> For DHCP relay and DHCP proxy, packets sent to the DHCP server from the router have both the source and destination UDP ports set to 67. The DHCP server responds using the same ports.

- Maybe there are some methods but I can't find out until now ?