# Instances can't get any IP from the DHCP server in OPENSTACK

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I have openstack wallaby running in two vm in VBox with Ubuntu 20.04, Controller and compute1. Everything runs without issues in provider network flat type except the dhcp.
For example, I have a network created in the range of 192.168.8.20-192.168.8.30. I selected to have a DHCP.
The instance gets an ip and runs, but when running it I can't get a response from the DHCP, like it did not exist. I mean, the port is attached to the DCHP with the ip 192.168.8.20.
I can even connect to it running ip netns.

```
root@controller:/home/stack# ip netns list
qdhcp-36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f (id: 0)
```

When i try to ping the instance ip from the DHCP to the instance using netns the dhcp server did not get any response from the instance or any device in the network. The network works, because if I setup the ip manually in the instance I can get access to the gateway. But it didn't see the DHCP server, sending DHCP_DISCOVER without any response.

- Address -> 192.168.8.0/24 *36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f*
- Subnet -> 192.168.8.120,192.168.8.130 *09c143c9-0225-4951-bd9c-61846b8078a1*
- DHCP -> 192.168.8.120 *f4b2f7ba-c9e8-493d-a010-852e72f46ef7*
- Instance -> 192.168.8.22 *53316673-b6eb-4880-866f-91b1613aa17c*

The process:

```
root@controller:/home/stack# ps aux | grep dnsmasq
nobody      3616  0.0  0.0  12144   364 ?        S    18:11   0:00 dnsmasq --no-hosts --no-resolv --pid-file=/var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/pid --dhcp-hostsfile=/var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/host --addn-hosts=/var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/addn_hosts --dhcp-optsfile=/var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/opts --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/leases --dhcp-match=set:ipxe,175 --dhcp-userclass=set:ipxe6,iPXE --local-service --bind-dynamic --dhcp-range=set:subnet-09c143c9-0225-4951-bd9c-61846b8078a1,192.168.8.0,static,255.255.255.0,86400s --dhcp-option-force=option:mtu,1500 --dhcp-lease-max=256 --conf-file=/dev/null --domain=openstacklocal
root        6278  0.0  0.0   6380  2380 pts/1    S+   18:59   0:00 grep --color=auto dnsmasq
```

And the log from /var/log/syslog

```
Nov  6 19:05:10 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: DHCPRELEASE(ns-f4b2f7ba-c9) 192.168.8.128 fa:16:3e:24:74:93 
Nov  6 19:05:10 controller dnsmasq[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/addn_hosts - 1 addresses
Nov  6 19:05:10 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/host
Nov  6 19:05:10 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/opts
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/addn_hosts - 2 addresses
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/host
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/opts
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/addn_hosts - 2 addresses
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/host
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/opts
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/addn_hosts - 2 addresses
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/host
Nov  6 19:05:30 controller dnsmasq-dhcp[3616]: read /var/lib/neutron/dhcp/36c8f4db-ccfc-483b-a5ff-868185dcce0f/opts
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is. You write that the instance is getting the IP, so I would assume the DHCP server is reachable. But then you also write that the DHCP is not responding, can you clarify what exactly works and what not?

Comment: My instance gets an IP when its launched, but inside the vm can't get the IP from the dhcp. I had to configure it manually with the ip that openstack give me

Comment: You mean the VM gets an IP assigned from openstack (which you see in the dashboard or cli) but inside the VM the interface is not configured? That means you need to edit your base image so the interface is configured by DHCP.

Comment: I solved the issue. Using tcpdump I was able to trace packets from 67 and 68 from both machines. What happened was that Vbox for some reasons does no receive packets if it is not in promiscuous mode in the compute node

Comment: @Israel You means you run `DHCP server` in the instance and the `DHCP packet` not outside the compute node? If yes, maybe there is `security group` limit the **DHCP packet**, check from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783457/isc-dhcp-server-not-work-in-openstacks-instance-but-work-in-vmware